# Does the client can acquire the real address of the worker node through the response message

Tags: proxy, wso2, cluster-computing, reverse-proxy

In the typical cluster setting for WSO2 product,client send request to worker node through ELB,actually,the client send the request to the address of ELB.

The same applies to the reverse process,the client will receive the response message from the worker node throuht ELB,then the client can only acquire the address of ELB from the response message.

I want to know,can the client acquire the real address of the worker node which process the request from the responese message,and how to get it.

Does anyone know about it?

Comment: Please tag more carefully. This is not [tag:cluster-analysis] (a data mining technique, also known as "clustering")

Comment: Sorry, I should have tagged it more carefully.

Comment: Worker node address is an internal detail. Only the Load balancer knows it for routing the message. I think a client cannot get address etc. of the worker node which processed the request. Anyway what is the usecase for knowing this?

Comment: In the typical cluster setting for WSO2 product, all the request messages and response messages are both pass through the ELB. In some cases , it will make ELB overload. If the response message is sent back directly from the work node, it will relieve the burden of ELB.